# Property lists in LISP: are they used in real-life?

Tags: list, properties, lisp

Learning LISP I discovered that any object in LISP can have its own set of properties defined via property list. I wonder if such property lists are used in real-life LISP programming since (from my point of view) properties hide real object's structure?

I mean I can define the list in the way:

```
(:property1 value1 '(10 20 30))
```

or when property list is applied it would like just as:

```
('(10 20 30))
```

And no one will no idea that this list has hidden any property.

So when a property list should be used?

Comment: This concept is not universal across LISP dialects (e.g. it is not present in Scheme).

Comment: Can you reformulate your question? It makes litte sense.

Comment: The assumption of the question is not true. Symbols have property lists, not all objects.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs Lisp uses property lists extensively to record useful bits of information: where in source code a variable or function is defined, how to indent macros, what font faces to apply to chunks of text in a string or a buffer, and many other things. So the answer is yes, they are used in real life.

As well as the property lists associated with each symbol (not with each *object*, as Rörd points out), Emacs Lisp also lets you use property lists wherever else you find them convenient, since they're just ordinary lists. The functions for operating on symbol plists (`get`, `put` etc.) are different from the functions for operating on plists stored elsewhere (`plist-get`, `plist-put`). Common Lisp appears to make a [similar distinction](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node108.html), expressed a bit differently.